# How to create a list from a DefaultModelList so I can marshal to XML using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, defaultlistmodel

I am very new to this, so please be patient if I don't provide the right information.

I am trying to marshal data to xml using JAXB.  The data is in a DefaultListModel.  I am trying to move this data into a List that JAXB will recognize.  This attempt gives me an StackOverflowError:

```
    @XmlElement
    Window R = new Window ();
    {
        List r = new ArrayList(); 
        for( int index=0;index<8;index++ ) {
            try {
                r.add(order.elementAt(index));
            } finally {
            }
        }
    }
```

The DefaultListModel is "order"
Can I fix this or am I way off base on how to do this?  Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a class that contains List (generic parameters, please) r, and one would have to know the class of the list element. The annotation is misplaced. A little research - perhaps start at https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a class that has the list you want to marshal as a property:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Container {
    private List<Item> order;
    @XmlElement
    public List<Item> getOrder(){
        if( order == null ){
            order = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return order;
    }
}
```

You may have to annotate `Item` (or whatever the class name of your DefaultListModel's element).

The setter for order is typically omitted; one uses

```
container.getOrder().add( anotherItem );
```

to build the list.

Comment: That was really a great help!!! Thank you!! There were some other errors, so I had to make some other minor changes.  Here is a copy of the code that worked.